# Changing the contents of a TextCell according to the user input of another TextCell

Tags: gui-construction

Is it possible to change TextCells in the following code in that way, that the TextCell "profile starts at x =" changes to "profile starts at y =" and at the same time the TextCell "measurement starts at y =" changes to "measurements starts at x =" when the input of the user is "y" in the TextCell "direction of the profile (x / y)"?

Moreover I don't know why "TextAlignment -> Right" has no effect...

Here is the code:

```
code = ""; ffn = ""; lfn = ""; add = 0; direction = "x"; rs = ""; \
length = ""; startmeasurement = ""; distance = "";
DialogInput[
  Grid[{{Grid[{{TextCell["Code (004p):", FontSize -> 16, 
         TextAlignment -> Right], 
        InputField[Dynamic[code], String, 
         FieldSize -> {10, 1}]}}]}, {Grid[{{TextCell[
         "first filenumber:", FontSize -> 16, TextAlignment -> Right],
         InputField[Dynamic[ffn], Number, FieldSize -> {10, 1}],

        TextCell["last filenumber:", FontSize -> 16, 
         TextAlignment -> Right], 
        InputField[Dynamic[lfn], Number, FieldSize -> {10, 1}],

        TextCell["addition to filenumber", FontSize -> 16, 
         TextAlignment -> Right], 
        InputField[Dynamic[add], Number, FieldSize -> {10, 1}]},

       {TextCell["direction of the profile (x / y):", FontSize -> 16, 
         TextAlignment -> Right], 
        InputField[Dynamic[direction], String, FieldSize -> {2, 1}],

        TextCell["profile starts at x =", FontSize -> 16, 
         TextAlignment -> Right], 
        InputField[Dynamic[rs], Number, FieldSize -> {10, 1}],

        TextCell["length of the profile [m]:", FontSize -> 16, 
         TextAlignment -> Right], 
        InputField[Dynamic[length], Number, FieldSize -> {10, 1}]},

       {TextCell["measurement starts at y =", FontSize -> 16, 
         TextAlignment -> Right], 
        InputField[Dynamic[startmeasurement], Number, 
         FieldSize -> {10, 1}],

        TextCell["Distance between profiles (+0.5 / -0.5):", 
         FontSize -> 16, TextAlignment -> Right], 
        InputField[Dynamic[distance], Number, FieldSize -> {10, 1}]}},
       Frame -> All],


     DefaultButton[DialogReturn[og]]}}], 
  NotebookEventActions -> {"ReturnKeyDown" :> 
     FrontEndExecute[NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "\n"]]}];
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: +1 I'm puzzled that someone marked this as a favorite question without upvoting it.

Comment: Sometimes I'll mark my own questions as favorite so that it keep the question along with all my other favorites.  But I am not allowed outvote my own post.  So this could be why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.  Just replace

```
TextCell["profile starts at x =", FontSize -> 16, 
     TextAlignment -> Right]
```

With

```
 Dynamic[TextCell["profile starts at" <> ToString[direction] <> " =", FontSize -> 16, TextAlignment -> Right]]
```

and

```
TextCell["measurement starts at y =", FontSize -> 16,  TextAlignment -> Right]
```

by

```
Dynamic[TextCell["measurement starts at " <> ToString[direction]<> " =", FontSize -> 16, TextAlignment -> Right]
```

Since you only want direction to be "x" or "y" you may want to use a different control object such as a popupmenu:

```
  code = ""; ffn = ""; lfn = ""; add = 0; directions = {"x","y"}; rs = ""; \
  length = ""; startmeasurement = ""; distance = ""; choice=1;
  DialogInput[
  Grid[{{Grid[{{TextCell["Code (004p):", FontSize -> 16, 
     TextAlignment -> Right], 
    InputField[Dynamic[code], String, 
     FieldSize -> {10, 1}]}}]}, {Grid[{{TextCell[
     "first filenumber:", FontSize -> 16, TextAlignment -> Right],
     InputField[Dynamic[ffn], Number, FieldSize -> {10, 1}],

    TextCell["last filenumber:", FontSize -> 16, 
     TextAlignment -> Right], 
    InputField[Dynamic[lfn], Number, FieldSize -> {10, 1}],

    TextCell["addition to filenumber", FontSize -> 16, 
     TextAlignment -> Right], 
    InputField[Dynamic[add], Number, FieldSize -> {10, 1}]},

   {TextCell["direction of the profile (x / y):", FontSize -> 16, 
     TextAlignment -> Right], 
   PopupMenu[Dynamic[choice], {1-> "x", 2-> "y"}],

    Dynamic[TextCell["profile starts at "<>directions[[choice]]<> " =", FontSize -> 16, 
     TextAlignment -> Right]], 
    InputField[Dynamic[rs], Number, FieldSize -> {10, 1}],

    TextCell["length of the profile [m]:", FontSize -> 16, 
     TextAlignment -> Right], 
    InputField[Dynamic[length], Number, FieldSize -> {10, 1}]},

   {Dynamic[TextCell["measurement starts at "<>directions[[Mod[choice+1,2,1]]]<> " =", FontSize -> 16, 
     TextAlignment -> Right]], 
    InputField[Dynamic[startmeasurement], Number, 
     FieldSize -> {10, 1}],

    TextCell["Distance between profiles (+0.5 / -0.5):", 
     FontSize -> 16, TextAlignment -> Right], 
    InputField[Dynamic[distance], Number, FieldSize -> {10, 1}]}},
   Frame -> All],


 DefaultButton[DialogReturn[og]]}}], 
 NotebookEventActions -> {"ReturnKeyDown" :> 
 FrontEndExecute[NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "\n"]]}];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is it!! And also for your great idea adding a popupmenu. Fantastic.

Comment: Hi, one TextCell is not exactly working correct. The code is: {Dynamic[TextCell["measurement starts at " <> direction <> " =", 
   FontSize -> 16, TextAlignment -> Right]]. But it should show just the opposite direction chosen in the other TextCell, not the same... How can this be managed?

Comment: I changed it so it works now

Comment: Thanks a lot, apart from being more or less a beginner with Mathematica, I would have never found a solution for that...